# How to update a table according to another tables values SQL

Tags: sql

Hello i have two tables First table is called `time` and it has rows

```
Id,time,status,doctor
```

Second table is called `appointments` and it has rows

```
Id,doctorname,doctoremail,patientname,service,comment,time,date,status
```

The first table shows only time schedules options (08:00 until 16:00) and if `status=1` for a specific time (08:00 has status=1) this time option wont show since is already booked.

The appointments saves values from the past, current day and future. I want to make an update query where the second table `appointments` updates the status of first table `time` if there are any todays date appointments.

Something like this

```
update time set status='0' where time=(select time from appointments where date='05/12/2022' and doctoremail='something@gmail.com')
```

Is it possible to do such a query?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please take care to avoid misleading questions: A query always starts with "SELECT" and doesn't change data.  That's why it's named a "query". A "command" changes data. To your question: Did you try out before asking this? Your update commands looks like being valid on first glance (except the issue an in clause could be necessary instead of "=" ), so does it change the data as intended or not?

Comment: @JonasMetzler the query doesnt work because there is more then 1 value in it to update

Comment: Yes, therefore I mentioned you might need to replace the "=" in your command by "IN" -> you have "where time=..." -> must likely be changed to "where time IN...". It would be great to see some sample data. Could you please add them?

Comment: @JonasMetzler yes i will add it and test it

Comment: @JonasMetzler Yes it worked with IN, it makes the specific values with status='0' this is the query `update time set status='0' where  doctor='something@gmail.com' and time IN (select time from appointments where date='05/12/2022' and doctoremail='something@gmail.com')`

Answer (score 0):

As [@Jona Metzler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18794826/jonas-metzler) helped me the final query that works is

```
update time set status='0' where  doctor='something@gmail.com' and time IN (select time from appointments where date='05/12/2022' and doctoremail='something@gmail.com')
```